# a query to get last message of each distinct row

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have an SQLite table with the following structure:

```
create table Message (
    _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    convo_id text,
    isSender BOOLEAN,
    isRead BOOLEAN,
    message text,
    time timestamp default (strftime('%s', 'now'))
);
```

It stores all the messages for each friend having a unique convo_id.

I want a query to get the *last message* for each convo_id (or in other words, last message of each friend).

Comment: I was thinking 

Since **_id** is autoincrement , so somehow if I can  get max(**_id**) of each **convo_id** , I can get the last Message from those returned **_id**s

Comment: What @Rezoan meant was if you tried writing a query yourself before asking it on SO? If there's a problem with your query, add it to your question and we'll help you.  That said, you need to sort your result by timestamp and limit the number of results to 1 for each convo_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find out the last timestamp for each `convo_id`:

```
SELECT convo_id,
       MAX(time) AS time
FROM Message
GROUP BY convo_id
```

Then, use these values to filter the records of the original table:

```
SELECT Message.*
FROM Message
JOIN (SELECT convo_id,
             MAX(time) AS time
      FROM Message
      GROUP BY convo_id)
USING (convo_id, time)
```

If you have SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can do everything in a single step:

```
SELECT *,
       MAX(time)
FROM Message
GROUP BY convo_id
```

Comment: Its working on my Android API 10 that supports Sqlite 3.6, in short your single step solution works for lower versions also . Thnx

Comment: It is not guaranteed to work (especially if the largest time is not stored last in the table).

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this:

```
select convo_id,message from Message where (convo_id,_id) IN (select convo_id,max(_id) as _id from Message group by convo_id);
```

Might contain syntax errors. I didn't try it on my PC.